# “The assembly to be debugged was built with a platform incompatible with the current system.”

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, debugging

I am using Visual studio professional 2019, Version 16.6.0 dot net framework 4.8.03761. 
I updated the visual studio and now my C# applications will not debug.

Target Framework is .net 4.7.2 
Output type is Windows Application.

Under build Platform target is set to ANY CPU
Prefer 32 bit is unchecked.

My system is 64 bit Windows 10 Enterprise.

I get "Error while trying to run project: Cannot start debugging. The assembly to be debugged was built with a platform incompatible with the current system."

This is now happening with all my C# solutions.

I believe there is a configuration setting somewhere I am missing.

This application is a standard C# application it does not use any externally built DLL it was built created with the wizard for c#.

The application worked fine until I updated Visual studio. to the newest version.

I have reinstalled - repaired the installation/

I have selected **Any CPU** in configurations.

If I change the configuration it to x64 or x86 it will work but not after I reload the project. 
I then have to delete the configuration and recreate it for it to debug.

The application will execute outside of the debugger on the command line and launch the UI with no issues.

Configuration Properties are set to Debug Any CPU with the Build box checked.

If someone else loads the solution in the visual studio the application works and debugs fine.

I have deleted the application and reloaded from the base that works from configuration management, unchanged from when it worked. I get the same issue.

Comment: have you tried changing settings at solution level not on project level?

Comment: Did you try to remove `.vs` folder in solution root? Also remove `bin` and `obj` folders, then try to rebuild the solution

Comment: I have removed .vs folder and I did it at the project level and solution level. I deleted the project completely and restored from svn from when it worked. I believe this is a visual studio issue, not a project issue.

Comment: Maybe a registry setting because I opened a project that did not have the issue and rebuilt and I have the same issue with it and all these solutions work for someone else as is.

Comment: I found the Error thanks for the effort it seems a user variable was set for the platform when cross-compiling another application this was not cleaned up and it caused the visual studio to inadvertently set the Platform architecture to ARM so no matter what you set the platform to debug it was defaulting to the system environment variable. when the debugger launches I think it validates against this environment variable set for the system and not the project it seems like a bug. Removing the environment variable resolved the issue. I could not find a reference to this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, it seems a user variable was set for the platform when cross-compiling another application this was not cleaned up and it caused Visual studio to inadvertently set the Platform architecture to ARM so no matter what you set the platform to while debugging in the UI it was defaulting to the system environment variable. When the debugger launches I think it validates against this environment variable set for the system and not the project it seems like a bug. Removing the environment variable specifying the platform resolves the issue.

A link to the list of env variables used by Visual Studio

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019

As a note, if using multiple build systems and visual studio it is possible to have conflicts with visual studio platform options that are not reset by the solution when changing configurations within the configuration manager.